# Magento grouped product

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have created one group product containing many associated products. On product page I am adding that associated(simple) products of grouped product to one container. Then after clicking on ADD TO CART all associated products are showing differently with their quantity and prizes. But I want to show then as one group like single product. And price and quantity will be addition of all the associated products. Is there any way to do this? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the selection of products as a unity, you should use `bundle product` which is aimed to do this.